How can I create zoom functionality for Sankey Networks using networkD3 and htmlwidgets?
As i the title says. I would like to zoom interactively on Sankey networks, as it is for example possible for Force networks. I assume that it would work by adding a htmlwidgets::onRender() call, containing JS().
I would like to do so via a wrapper around sankeyNetwork() as i have done (badly) with a custom hover tooltip. When i try to use this aproach for zooming i get a lot of uncaught errors; I am a JS noob.
My code is a mess and my question is so general that I belive that no reprex is necessary. If it is necessary, please ask.
Example of (bad) wrapper:
sankeyNetworkWithAge <- function(Links, Nodes, Source, Target, Value, 
                                 NodeID, NodeGroup = NodeID, 
                                 LinkGroup = NULL, ...) {
  # Print debug information
  print("Creating base widget...")
  
  # Create the base widget with tryCatch to catch any errors
  widget <- tryCatch({
    sankeyNetwork(
      Links = Links,
      Nodes = Nodes,
      Source = Source,
      Target = Target,
      Value = Value,
      NodeID = NodeID,
      NodeGroup = NodeGroup,
      LinkGroup = LinkGroup,
      ...
    )
  }, error = function(e) {
    print(paste("Error creating widget:", e$message))
    return(NULL)
  })
  
  # Check if widget creation was successful
  if (is.null(widget)) {
    stop("Failed to create base widget")
  }
  
  print("Adding custom data...")
  
  # Add custom data
  widget$x$options$median_age <- Links$median_age
  
  print("Adding custom JavaScript...")
  
  # Add custom JavaScript
  widget <- htmlwidgets::onRender(
    widget,
    '
        function(el, x) {
            console.log("Running custom JavaScript");
            var medianAges = x.options.median_age;
            
            d3.select(el)
                .selectAll(".link")
                .each(function(d, i) {
                    d.median_age = medianAges[i];
                })
                .select("title")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.source.name + " → " + d.target.name + "\\n" +
                           d.value + " Candidates\\n" +
                           "Median Age: " + d.median_age;
                });
        }
        '
  )
  
  print("Returning widget...")
  return(widget)
}


Why do you need to write your own thing? Why not use plotly: https://plotly.com/r/sankey-diagram/?

Inertia I guess, I was not aware that plotly had this and have been using networkD3 for some time. If nobody will answer until Friday then I guess I will have to learn it. Thanks for the suggestion. Is there a up do date website that shows the best visualization tools in R? Most pages I came across didn’t mention plotly at all, and I guess I will need a refresher anyway. Thank you.

I haven't previously looked for such resource, but just googled it (best R packages for visualization) and a couple of good pages were at the top (p.s. plotly is probably 2nd most famous visualization package in r after ggplot).

I wouldn't say I recommend this, but here you go...
library(networkD3)

URL <- paste0(
  "https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/",
  "master/JSONdata/energy.json")
Energy <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL)

widget <- sankeyNetwork(Links = Energy$links, Nodes = Energy$nodes, Source = "source",
              Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
              units = "TWh", fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)

widget <- htmlwidgets::onRender(
  widget,
  '
    function(el, x) {
      var zoom = d3.zoom();
      function redraw() {
        d3.select(el).select("g")
          .attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
      }
      zoom.on("zoom", redraw);

      d3.select(el).select("svg")
        .attr("pointer-events", "all")
        .call(zoom);
    }
  '
)

print(widget)


Thank you, it works as exactly as i wanted. Is there a specific reason aside from poor maintainability and ugly code, that makes you nor recommend it?

It’s just adding a layer of complexity that it wasn’t necessarily designed for, so it might have unintended consequences under certain conditions
